# I want "L" column automatic in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is my current sheet where data in "L" columns come from columns "G to I" but in reference of columns "A to D". But as you can see i set formula manually for "L2" and "L3", So i want to make "L" column dynamic for fill "L" column to end of sheet.

Column reference note: 
I pulling one data(A2,B2,C2) from "G,H,I" to "L" column, and eight data(D2) from "J" column.

 [GoogleSheetLink](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mO9SNDtIe7ego_OL6KSb5yiBE0P_C7F_MC0KFFfERls/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: This is my current sheet where data in "L" columns come from columns "G to I" but in reference of columns "A to D"]

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet? That will make it easier for us to provide a solution.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mO9SNDtIe7ego_OL6KSb5yiBE0P_C7F_MC0KFFfERls/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell N2 I entered this formula

```
=textjoin(", ", 1, offset($G$2,0,0,A2,1), offset($H$2,0,0,B2,1), offset($I$2,0,0,C2,1), offset($J$2,0,0,D2,1))
```

and filled down.

See if that works for you?